# Changes show up in view source but not live site

Tags: author

Live link: http://beertournament.com/

Type in YYYYY in source code to see relevant section of source code. If you hover over "Tree House" on the live site, you should one url but if you look in the source code, you should see a different url.

1st thought is that front page is cached but I don't have a live cache plugin at the moment.

Here is the code section if that helps:

```
`<?php if ( !is_page() ) :
        $author_posts_url = the_author_link();
            $posts_by_title   = sprintf(
            __( 'Posts by %1$s ( @%2$s )', 'p2-breathe' ),
            get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ),
            get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' )
        ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $author_posts_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="author-avatar">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $author_posts_url ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php if ( ! is_page() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( the_author_link() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="entry-author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="entry-date">`
```

Updated with screenshot links in comments.

Update 1: Updated to this code....

```
<?php if ( !is_page() ) :
            $author_posts_url = the_author_link();
        $posts_by_title   = sprintf(
        __( 'Posts by %1$s ( @%2$s )', 'p2-breathe' ),
        get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ),
        get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' )
    ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $author_posts_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="author-avatar">
    <?php echo get_avatar( $author_posts_url ); ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="entry-meta">
    <?php if ( ! is_page() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(the_author_ID()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="entry-author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="entry-date">
```

Update 2 - here is the content.php code: http://pastebin.com/QHH24ha2

Comment: Hello Adam, what exactly is the problem? Can you add more details to your question

Comment: See 1st step here to see problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tyHL_ursCSWTZTQy10TVlhN00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See 2nd step here to see how link doesn't match hover: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tyHL_ursCSR0l0SjhKSHl5eE0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You are echoing the author link generator inside an already opened anchor tag, which is causing error. Try this code:

**Method 1**

```
<?php if ( !is_page() ) :
        $author_posts_url = the_author_link();
            $posts_by_title   = sprintf(
            __( 'Posts by %1$s ( @%2$s )', 'p2-breathe' ),
            get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ),
            get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' )
        ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $author_posts_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="author-avatar">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $author_posts_url ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php if ( ! is_page() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="entry-author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="entry-date">
```

Noticed that i replaced `echo esc_url( the_author_link() );` with `get_author_posts_url()` which will only return the URL, not a full anchor.

You may also want to use `get_author_posts_url(the_author_ID())` if the code didn't work at the first place.

**Method 2**

If you are not running this code in a loop and don't have access to the author ID, you can change the following line:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( the_author_link() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="entry-author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
```

to:

```
<?php the_author_link(); ?>
```

Which will still return a link to author page, but without `class="entry-author"` which i don't think would be a great deal since you can tweak your css to achieve the same result.

Comment: If you see my updated code (I edited original post), that is what I put in there now onto live site.

Comment: We're in the loop. Here is full content.php: http://pastebin.com/QHH24ha2

Comment: I investigated your source code while you were testing method 1 and noticed everything is correct. The only reason the link is altered in live page can be a script. I noticed you have a plugin called O2 which is probably injecting the URL in your author link at around line 1015 of your source code. Try disabling the plugin and see if it works.

Comment: Ah I see you are correct. Disabling the plugin yielded the desired result but took out too much functionality so I'll have to keep that link and see if I can change that meta section at all using the child theme code. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52169/discussion-between-adam-and-sasan-j).